# Unable subtract days from date in java

Tags: java, date, time, epoch, java.util.date

I want to subtract days from date in java. But I **dont want to use external libraries**. I have referred some of questions from stackoverflow but they are suggesting to use external libraries. So I have applied following logic

```
noOfDays = 24;
Date compareDate = new Date(currentDate - noOfDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("compare date " + compareDate);
```

It is working fine till 24 days.But after 24 days it is giving unexpected result. Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: Use Java.util.Calendar

Comment: joda can be your best friend here

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa OP do not want to use third-Party libs

Comment: My current time is in epoch. How can I fit that in calender object.

Comment: @SuyashKharade Please add a minimal runable example.

Comment: A day is not always exactly 24 hours (think about daylight savings transitions, where a day can be 23 or 25 hours), so subtracting number of days times 24 hours is not always correct.

Comment: Use the new Date-Time API in Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/

Comment: @SuyashKharade Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed many many times already.

Comment: I have checked all the questions. Everyone is suggesting third party libs. That's why I posted this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)).
Something like that:

```
Calendar c = new Calendar()
c.setTime(currentDate);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, noOfDays)
compareDate = c.getTime()
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens. It solved my problem.

Comment: This Answer is now outdated. See the modern solution using *java.time* in the [Answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36576345/642706).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (which is part of the JDK since Java 8):

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate compareDate = today.minusDays(24);
```

Answer (score 0):

You computation is about integers, which won't fit higher values than the max integer value.

Declare your variable as a `long` :

```
long noOfDays = 24;
Date compareDate = new Date(currentDate - noOfDays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.out.println("compare date " + compareDate);
```

However, as the comments said, this is not the best approach for substracting days, so have a look at better solutions in other answers.